# How does one create an extension loader in Python?

Tags: python, module

I want to improve a Python framework that I'm writing by having it enumerate and load modules from some specified folder, at runtime, based on certain properties that the modules may have.

Probably properties such as: only modules that contain a certain value (like a tag) in some metadata field, or perhaps only modules that contain a class that derives from a certain base class.

For example, let's say that the extensions are plug-ins that support different types of authentication--I'd like my framework to discover the possible plug-ins at run-time without requiring explicit configuration.

It seems like this sort of "extension loading" should be possible, and has probably been done a zillion times before, none of the search queries that have thought to try are turning anything up, and I don't know a good specific project that already implements this to start by reading someone else's approach.

Any pointers on approaches that would work to build such a thing (or even advice on a more Pythonic way to think about this problem) would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(A *good* answer for this would give an overview and options, so don't rush to accept my quick answer.)

I do this with one of my projects to load classes all the modules in a package without using `import *` and hardcoding names. The code is viewable in context on [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/esec/source/browse/esec/esec/species/__init__.py#767).

```
SPECIES = []
'''An automatically generated list of the available species types.'''

def _do_import():
    '''Automatically populates SPECIES with all the modules in this
    folder.

    :Note:
        Written as a function to prevent local variables from being
        imported.
    '''
    import os

    for _, _, files in os.walk(__path__[0]):
        for filename in (file for file in files if file[0] != '_' and file[-3:] == '.py'):
            modname = filename[:filename.find('.')]
            mod = __import__(modname, globals(), fromlist=[])
            for cls in (getattr(mod, s) for s in dir(mod)):
                if cls is not Species and type(cls) is type and issubclass(cls, Species):
                    if getattr(cls, '_include_automatically', True):
                        SPECIES.append(cls)
                        globals()[cls.__name__] = cls

_do_import()
```

Comment: That's definitely good enough to get me started. Mostly what I needed to understand was the existence of `__import__()`, and now I can take this as a starting point and get where I need to get.